# Power Shell Scripts that will delete logs on folder and subfolder

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

Calling Power Shell Guru's =)

Can anybody help me on creating power shell scripts that will delete log file on folder including logs on sub-folder?

Comment: -1. Please read the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) to improve your questions in the future. Also you should use "Get-Help Get-ChildItem -full" and "Get-Help Remove-Item -full"

Answer (score 3):

Assuming what you want is to delete all files with the extension log for a directory specified in the variable logpath:

```
$logpath = "C:\ExamplePath\MyLogFiles"
Get-ChildItem $logpath -recurse *.log -force | Remove-Item -force
```

Comment: How do I add older than 15 days should be delete?

Comment: `Get-ChildItem $logpath -recurse *.log -force  | where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).adddays(-15)} | Remove-Item -force`

Comment: its works! but what if my logs has different extension like *.txt and *.err how i separate them?

Comment: @Sonn put the series of extensions as an array, i.e. `gci $logpath -recurse *log,*txt,*err ...`

Comment: @Sonn when you use `-Recurse` switch use the `-Filter` parameter like this `Get-ChildItem $logpath -Recurse -Include *.log, *.err, *.txt -force | where {$_.lastwritetime -lt (get-date).adddays(-15)} | Remove-Item -force`

Comment: @Sonn try this: `gci -path $logpath -include *log,*txt,*err ...`